# Is there a successor module for 'Upload Image'?

Tags: 7, rating

I have 'inherited' a d5 site that I would like to relaunch on d7. It made heavy use of the module [Upload Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/upload_image), turning attached images into nodes.

I'm now looking for a solution to implement that functionality – but so far I couldn't find a proper successor to the *Upload Image* module. Why I need the attached images to be nodes: the user uploading the images should only fill in 1 form – but users viewing the pages should be able to vote on every image separately ([fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar)). I'm currently a bit lost. Maybe I'm overthinking this?

Any pointers / suggestions appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try [Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/image) module, it has similar functionality

**Notes**:

- I looked in code of this module. Unfortunately it contains some legacy code and obsolete functions. In this case try the [Image Attach](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_attach) module.
- Quote from [Image Attach README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/image_attach/tree/README.txt):

  > You should use Image Attach if:
  >
  > - You want images that you attach to content to also be pieces of content in their own right, that can be viewed separately.
  > - You want reusable images (note that other ways of doing this exist).
  > - You want images that have meta-data, such as a title, description, author, and so on.
  > - You want to be able to change the file for an image, while keeping it attached to other content and keeping the rest of its data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer – I tried that because the module description looked promising (although it is marked "absolete") but trying to install the *image* module I get "*Error: ImageMagick Advanced Options is already installed*" – so I can't install the *Image* module atm… :/

Comment: I looked in code of this module. Unfortunately it contains some legacy code and obsolete functions. In this case try https://www.drupal.org/project/image_attach module

Comment: Quote from Image attach Readme 
You should use Image Attach if:

* You want images that you attach to content to also be pieces of content in
  their own right, that can be viewed separately.
* You want reusable images (note that other ways of doing this exist).
* You want images that have meta-data, such as a title, description, author,
  and so on.
* You want to be able to change the file for an image, while keeping it attached
  to other content and keeping the rest of its data.

Comment: It seems to do the trick.